# How to show 2 decimal place in a list?

Tags: python

```
x = [2312.9940205276557, 0.173049872715771, -10000]

xnpv = []
xnpv.append(x[0]) = [2312.9940205276557]
```

I would like to show it in 2 decimal place.

I used `print('X NPV: {:.2f}.'.format(xnpv))`

Error message is TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.**format**

Is there other code to show it?

Comment: What are you doing here `xnpv.append(x[0]) = [2312.9940205276557]`? It throws an error.

Comment: I wanted it to be 1 item in the list only. So when I present my answer, it would be easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use round [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)

for all elements :

```
x = [2312.9940205276557, 0.173049872715771, -10000]

y = [round(i,2) for i in x ]
```

output :

```
[2312.99, 0.17, -10000]
```

for one element use `round(x[0], 2)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an element to be printed as:

```
print('X NPV: {:.2f}.'.format(xnpv[0]))
```

or use a loop to print all the values of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the round function to limit the number of decimal places by first shifting the decimals over to the left according to how many decimals you want, rounding and then shifting back to the right.

```
def limit_decimals(element: float, n: int):
    # element is the number you want to round, 
    # n is the number of decimals you want to round to
    return round(element*10**n)/10**n
```

Edit: Alternatively you can limit the amount of decimals print produces as another answer pointed out. I would recommend that approach because you don't need to allocate extra memory.